# How to compare each date in a cell with all the dates in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns lets say

```
Name  Address Date
faraz  xyz    2022-01-01
Abdul  abc    2022-06-06
Zara   qrs    2021-02-25
```

I want to compare each date in Date column with all the other dates in the Date column and only keep those rows which lie within 6 months of atleast one of all the dates.

```
for example: (2022-01-01 - 2022-06-06) = 5 months so we keep both these dates
but, 
(2022-06-06 - 2021-02-25) and (2022-01-01 - 2021-02-25) exceed the 6 month limit 
so we will drop that row.
```

Desired Output:

```
Name  Address Date
faraz  xyz    2022-01-01
Abdul  abc    2022-06-06
```

I have tried a couple of approches such a nested loops, but I got 1 million+ entries and it takes forever to run that loop. Some of the dates repeat too. Not all are unique.

```
for index, row in dupes_df.iterrows():

    for date in uniq_dates_list:

        format_date = datetime.strptime(date,'%d/%m/%y')

        if (( format_date.year - row['JournalDate'].year ) * 12 + ( format_date.month - row['JournalDate'].month ) <= 6):

            print("here here")
            break
        else:
            dupes_df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

I need a much more omptimal solution for it. Studied about lamba functions, but couldn't get to the depths of it.

Comment: Let me understand the goal better. Say that you have all the dates sorted in a list (the solution you are looking for uses sorting first for efficiency), which ones do you want filtered out? As far as I understood you want out those which are standing alone in a year period (so no other dates 6m before and no 6m after), did I get it right?

Comment: Lambdas will not help you, they are introduced as a shorthand to an anonumous function, not as a way to improve efficiency.

Comment: No no. I do want before and after possibilty as well. lets say if the date was 
2021-11-01
it would count as (2021-11-01 - 2022-01-01) <= 6 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Name;Address;Date
faraz;xyz;2022-01-01
Abdul;abc;2022-06-06
Zara;qrs;2021-02-25
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';', parse_dates=['Date'])

df_date = pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, reverse=True) for l in itertools.combinations(df['Date'], 2)], columns=['Date1', 'Date2'])
df_date['diff'] = (df_date['Date1'] - df_date['Date2']).dt.days
df[df.Date.isin(df_date[df_date['diff'] <= 180].iloc[:, :-1].T[0])]
```

Output:

```
    Name Address       Date
0  faraz     xyz 2022-01-01
1  Abdul     abc 2022-06-06
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. It works like a charm. I made some improvements in your solution. I filtered out all the unique dates first in a list.


`uniq_dates_list = df['Date'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y").unique().tolist()`

then instead of making combinations of df['Date'] column I made combinations of uniq_dates_list as some dates repeat

`df_date = pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, reverse=True) for l in itertools.combinations(uniq_dates_list, 2)], columns=['Date1', 'Date2'])`

 and then ran the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

First I think it's be easier if you use 'relativedelta' from 'dateutil'.

Reference: https://pynative.com/python-difference-between-two-dates-in-months/

Second, I think you need to add a column, let's call it `score`.

At the second loop, if delta <= 6 month :

```
set score = 1 and 'continue'
```

This way each row is compared to all rows.

Delete all rows that have score == 0.